# How to fix TCP stream in Wireshark with spurious retransmission?

Tags: wireshark, packet, ctf

This was for a [CTF](https://challenges.reply.com/tamtamy/challenges/category/cybersecurity) (it ended yesterday, so I'm not cheating), but I've spent so many hours on it that I really just want to understand what I should have done.

Here is the [PasteBin Hex Dump](https://pastebin.com/H09g6SA6). I imported and followed the TCP stream and get a flag, but it's not correct, looking at the packets there are several errors though, a spurious retransmission, some retransmissions and an unseen segment.

[image: screenshot]

I've read a ton about the errors and what they mean, but I must not understand it correctly, because nothing I tried worked. I tried following the seq and ack by hand, with the understanding of how it is they are supposed to increase, but again, I'm doing something wrong because I just get what Wireshark gives.

Hopefully this is an appropriate question, because I would love to know how to solve this so I can sleep at night again.